# How do I get rid of the glare in this photo?

Tags: exposure, lighting, overexposure, lighting-basics, glare

I wanted to know how to get rid of this glare on my lens, is this corrected using a filter?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Reduce the power of the background light in relation to the overall image.

   A Blown up white image in a background should be just barely overexposed. If you are using a histogram on the camera take pictures from darker to lighter untill you just get the overexposure on the white and **stop** there.

   If you are using an incident lightmeter overexpose to 1 or 2 stops the recomended exposition. This is in the case your background is really white If your background is gray you need to use the histogram aproach.
2. Make sure you have a very, very clean lens.
3. Increase the distance from your subject to the background.
4. Make sure you are focusing well. Try reducing the aperture.
5. But also the image looks like a very low quality lens is being used. A cellphone perhaps? This lenses are not as sharp as a good one.

---

Aditional note.

Compensate any changes in exposing the background to the lighting of your main subject.

Comment: Thanks for feed back, the lens that used is a 50mm 1.2 L lens so I probably messed up bad on that foto.

Comment: @ErikJosephMeek It looks like, in addition to missing exposure, you also hand held the camera at too slow a shutter time and camera movement made the image blurry. Either that or you missed focus fairly significantly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Ill take into consideration all your suggestions. That photo was a test shoot for the exposition of the flash, but that was the most prominent example I had.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to improve it in your favorite photo editor:

1. Convert to grayscale.
2. Adjust contrast of the gray image your favorite techniques.
3. Replace the luminosity of the original with the adjusted gray image.
4. Use overlay or multiply to adjust the colors.

[image: example]